# Stored procedure output parameter returning rounded value

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, output-parameter

I'm using output parameters to return values from a stored procedure.

Declaration in stored procedure is : `@GrandTtl DECIMAL(19,3) OUT`

The `SELECT` query is:

```
SET @GrandTtl = (SELECT TOP 1 Bill_Amount 
                 FROM Tbl_Restaurant_Kitchen_Order_Bill_Details 
                 WHERE Bill_Number = @billno)
```

For example, the select query returns the value `4087.67` then the output parameter value is returned as `4088` from SQL Server to C#.

Here is the C# code calling the stored procedure:

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Sp_RestCC_BillDetails", con);
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

SqlParameter OutParam26 = cmd.Parameters.Add("@GrandTtl", SqlDbType.Decimal,19);

da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);

con.Open();
da.Fill(ds, "dtRestCC_Items");
con.Close();

objRCCBEL.GrandTtlOut = Convert.ToDecimal(cmd.Parameters["@GrandTtl"].Value);
```

Comment: Can you also post the C# code that is calling this procedure?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You need to set up the C# parameter as

1. output -- obviously you've done this
2. decimal type, with a correct/compatible scale

---

```
SqlParameter parm = new SqlParameter("@GrandTtl", SqlDbType.Decimal); 
parm.Precision = 19;
parm.Scale = 3;
parm.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output; 
cmd.Parameters.Add(parm);
```

If you do not set the scale, the default is 0. Ref: [SqlParameter.Scale Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparameter.scale.aspx)

> > The number of decimal places to which Value is resolved. The default is 0.

Comment: This works for me thanks. But can we place the `Precision ` and `Scale ` in the source line?? like `SqlDbType.Decimal,19.3);` something like this ???

Comment: You'd need this version of the SqlParameter constructor: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5a10hy4y.aspx Just follow the C# example on the page

Answer (score 0):

According to [Microsoft](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd424925.aspx) decimal(p,s) should work for you. The money and smallmoneyt types are just a subset of decimal with precision of 4 places. So i think your problem comes from the type of the variable that is bound to the OUT parameter in C#.

Comment: i'm using decimal to set as outparameter. I also tried double but same problem persists